# Multithreaded HTTP Downloader

Tags: downloads, wget, download-manager, downloaders

I am looking for a command line tool that can download multiple urls with multiple threads e.g.

```
wget2 -n 5 http://stackoverflow.com/ http://askubuntu.com/ http://bobo.com/
```

Where `-n = number of threads`. I have come across Axel, but when I give it multiple URLs, it only downloads one.

I will be downloading HTML files.

Comment: Here are some answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430810/wget-download-with-multiple-connection-simultaneously and here is the same question on ask ubuntu: http://askubuntu.com/questions/214018/how-to-make-wget-faster-or-multithreading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the above and linked suggestions do not take two unique URLs. They only take URLs that are mirrors of the same file.

I've found a few programs that do this:

The best is puf (apt-get install puf), use puf url1 url2 etc.

Then there is HTTRACK, which requires a lot of tinkerings and has some limites I can't get past (speed and connection limits)

DownThemAll for Firefox is very good if you don't need a command line app.

**UPDATE**

I've since found puf has a tendency to crash. The best solution is to create a .txt file with URLs on new lines, e.g.

```
http://google.com/
http://yahoo.com/
```

Save that are urls.txt (for example) then run the command:

```
cat urls.txt | xargs -n 1 -P 10 wget -q
```

-n specifies to select each line from the file

-p specifies the number of URLs you would like to download in parallel.

Comment: Your question was not clear that you didn't want mirror options. uGet can do multiple files in a queue so I would suggest that over downthemall.

Comment: Can you multithread the dowload of this one file here http://askubuntu.com/q/813483/25388 ?

Comment: @Kohjah Breese based on the update for Batch Downloads, I'd suggest uGet because it has automatic batch support based on many different methods. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xhRy3Tx3phM

Answer (score 10):

Aria2 is the best solution for this if you want CLI. Aria2 supports multiple connections, multiple threads and multiple sources.

Another benefit of Aria2 is that is works as a plugin for uGet so you can use the power of Aria2 with a nice easy to use GUI.

Aria2 - CLI - http://aria2.sourceforge.net/

- by default, Aria2 does 5 connections but can be adjusted with the "-j" parameter.
- *aria2c -j 10 http://url.com/path/to/file.ext*

uGet - GUI - http://ugetdm.com

- multiple connections is adjustable in GUI when adding a download.

---

**Update: based on OP's batch needs**

[**uGet**](http://ugetdm.com/) supports batch downloads via .txt, .html, clipboard and many more methods. While admittedly not CLI, I think it solves the problem quite well. I created [a video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xhRy3Tx3phM) to explain the various methods, the GUI has changed since this recording but the functionality is still relevant.

Comment: Do you know the command to download multiple URLS?

I have tried:

aria2c -c http://www.google.com http://google.co.uk/zyzpage

And again it only downloads the first URL.

Comment: I don't know because I use uGet but here is the aria2 examples page from their wiki. http://aria2.sourceforge.net/manual/en/html/aria2c.html#example

Comment: This answer is stub. Can you please add code examples.

Comment: @Masi it's not a stub. Aria2 does the multi-connection and multi-threading by default. uGet provides this functionality through a GUI so no code to show. I'll edit the answer anyway.