# How to increase connection numbers in wget?

Tags: wget, download-manager

I want to increase my download speed (like download accelerators) in the `wget` command by increasing number of connections.

In the `aria2c` we can use `-x` option to recognize number of connections per server, but how we can do this in `wget`?

Comment: see the similar Q/A [How to make wget faster or multithreading?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/214018/how-to-make-wget-faster-or-multithreading) or have a look [wget download with multiple simultaneous connections](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430810/wget-download-with-multiple-simultaneous-connections) or use wget into a for loop. `for link in ${seq 10};do wget ... &;done`(not tested). `&` after wget command is important

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> wget -r -np -N [url] & wget -r -np -N [url] & wget -r -np -N [url] &
>   wget -r -np -N [url]

Just repeat the wget -r -np -N [url] for as many threads as you need… Now given this isn’t pretty and there are surely better ways to do this but if you want something quick and dirty it should do the trick… Enjoy!

*OR its better to do using following packages...*

---

try `axel`. [install axel](http://ubuntuguide.net/install-apt-fast-download-accelerator-in-ubuntu-12-0411-1010-04)

It is a fully fledged Command line based Downloader.
install axel and spawn download by
 `axel -a -n [Num_of_Thread] link1 link2 link3 ...`
 where '[Num_of_Thread]' is the number of parallel connections to create for each link you want to download.

-a just show an improved progress bar.

---

or you can use the aria2 :

```
aria2c -x 16 [url]
#          |
#          |
#          |
#          ----> the number of connections
```

http://aria2.sourceforge.net